# Installing pthread win32

Tags: pthreads-win32

I tried to install pthread win32 according to [this guide](http://linqtolinq.wordpress.com/2012/04/24/setting-up-pthreads-in-windows-under-visual-studio/).

I added the `pthreadVC2.dll` file to `C:\Windows` and the `pthreadVC2.lib` file to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib`. I typed `pthreadVC2.lib` in additional dependencies in linker but I couldn't include pthreads.h file in my project. Visual studio doesn't recognize this file. What's the problem?

I would like to get some help.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use MinGw for this purpose where lots of support is provided under this matter. You can use MinGW in Windows and the answer to this problem could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61457121/how-to-use-pthread-header-file-in-c-project-in-clion-which-uses-mingw-in-windows/61475020#61475020).

Answer (score 0):

The guide you followed has some issues. Your problem can be explained because the guide omitted to copy the header files to somewhere they will be found. A further problem is that the correct header file is pthread.h not pthreads.h.

If you wish to install pthread-win32 to your Visual Studio directory, the instructions on the following page may be more complete:

http://web.cs.du.edu/~sturtevant/pthread.html