# How to use pthread header file in C project in CLion which uses MinGW in windows

Tags: c, pthreads

I am trying to include `#include <pthread.h>` in my project which uses CLion but I am cannot use it directly. Is there any specific way to include pthread to a C project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally came up with a solution. Since I am using MinGW I used MinGW installation manager and installed packages that need to execute pthreads and openmp-related tasks in CLion. Here is the procedure.

After opening the installation manager go to all packages and select the select packages named using mingw32-pthreads-w32 and select them for installation.

[image]

Then go to the installation -> Apply changes to install new packages. The you can use pthread.h and omp.h inside your c or c++ program without any problem.

Answer (score 4):

Add **-lpthread** flag to the compilation, i.e:

```
 gcc foo.c -lpthread
```

more info here: [Why do you need '-lpthread'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59053585/why-do-you-need-lpthread)

Comment: Actually pthread file cannot be included since it is giving an file cannot found error.

Comment: Try to run this in a terminal: find / -name 'libpthread.so' -print